# docking control similar to visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, docking

Im looking for a docking control similar to visual studio. [For use in a c# program]

I've played around alot with the Weifen-Luo's Docking Library, which works great but is not quite right for what i'm working on. I need to be able to dock items within a tab control (or panel would work too) rather then within an mdi form.

The reason I'm looking to dock within in a tab is because with the current setup my main form has two tabs.

- one that runs the main program
- Another that has separate analysis tools.

Within the main tab I don't want any docking control.
But within the second tab I would like the user to be able to use docking with the tools.

I'm hoping for a free solution, maybe there is some mod I can make to the Weifen-Luo's Docking Library source.

I'm just looking for any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: WinForms or WPF? And docking within a tab control is a very strange thing to do; you're unlikely to find a library that supports it out of the box.

Comment: Win Forms. Ill edit to add a small explanation of why I want to dock within a tab and maybe another answer will come out of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work With the Free Weifen-Luo's Docking Library.

you can simply add your dock panel to a user control or a tab control or any other type of container.

```
Controls.Add(dockPanel);
```

The one thing that was missing was that in order to use the DockStyle.Document you must have the following line of code:

```
dockPanel.DocumentStyle = DocumentStyle.DockingWindow;
```

This allows DockStyle.Document to be used with something other then an MDI interface.

Answer (score 6):

For WPF, I can recommend AvalonDock. It's also used by SharpDevelop:

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Comment: I used avalondock while prototyping an app and it worked well.  Ended up using docking tools from DevExpress due client requirements and it worked well also.

Comment: I'm using win Forms but ill be sure to check it out anyhow, maybe I can just use the WPF ElementHost to make it work.

Comment: I believe DevExpress is what I want + it has several tools that can improve several of my existing programs. Weather we  go with it, that I don't know [since i was hoping for free] but so far I've been looking at the trial and it looks GREAT!!

Comment: One issue with the DevExpress is that the DockingStyles.Fill does not work appropriately