# How to make a Dockable Control in Visual Studios windows application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm newbie. I'm creating a windows application and I want to create a control similar to Visual Studios Property Panel or Solution Explorer Panel. That i can pin and unpin. How can I create that control? Do I have to add any DLL for that or I have to make my own control?

Also what is name of the control?

Comment: It is Dockable Control

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a property grid control in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343098/is-there-a-property-grid-control-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control is called Dockable Panel. A similar question already exists, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068122/docking-control-similar-to-visual-studio) to view that question.

You can use some third party controls.

[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUAr-I7iz-o)

[DevExpress](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1263)

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dock.aspx)

[Avalon Dock](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/)

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about a Docking interface. So your answer doesn't seem to answer the - to be fair, very vague - question.

Comment: He clearly mentioned in the question that he want a control similar to `property control` of `visual studios`.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i'm a newbie, so don't know much about the terms, this answer is correct

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It's the `System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid` control that you are after : [PropertyGrid Class (System.Windows.Forms)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what if it's a web application, wpf?